# Problem with viewing new documents in lyx

Tags: latex, pdflatex, lyx

I have installed a Hebrew installation of Lyx on my computer.

When I try to run the "view" command on the tutorial files they show up fine, but when I try to view any documents that I created I get a

> The external program pplatex finished with an error. It is
> recommended you fix the cause of the external program's error (check
> the logs).

error message. I have no idea what to do or where to check the logs, I am new to lyx and Latex in general.

many thanks to everyone!!!

Comment: You might want to look at Document > Settings > Fonts and copy whatever settings there are in the user guide to your new document. If you want to save those settings, you might want to click on the button "Save as Document Defaults". If that doesn't work, it might be a different document setting that is important. In that case, maybe just "save as" the LyX user guide to a new document. Then just delete the body and write your own body there.

Comment: I went to check your suggestion but then the tutorial files decided to fail as well. after that my computer has decided I suffered enough and offered me a new error message which said msvcr100.dll was missing. installed it and now everything works :)
thank you for your time!

Comment: Well, that's great you got it figured out somehow!

Answer (score 0):

After a few days my computer decided to share a new error message that said msvcr100.dll was missing. it was installed and now everything is fine.